# How to show fields based on picklist value in standard object opportunity..?

Tags: apex, standard-objects

I have Stage field in Opportunity. Stage is a picklist. I have Four text fields text1, text2, text3, text4. I don't want to display the these four text fields until i select "Closed Lost" in Stage field. means i don't want to display the four text fields before selecting the stage field as closed lost. When selecting the stage field as closed lost then i want to show the text fields. how to achieve this..? there is no visualforce page for opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it using standard declarative methods.

Pretty much all you can do with dependant fields you find here  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US

So either you have to start using a visualforce override or you'll see the fields permanently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about text values for Four text fields text1, text2, text3, text4.
Then go ahead and change field type to picklist and add your expected values.

By using field dependencies , create dependent picklist and map  text1, text2, text3, text4 values with opportunity stage picklist.

This is the only out of the box way to achieve this.
otherwise you need to go for custom VF page. :)